# pyspark spark-submit with environment.tar.gz working in cluster mode but not in client mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
spark-submit --conf "spark.executorEnv.PYTHONPATH=app" \
              --conf "spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYTHONPATH=app" \
              --conf "spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./environment/bin/python" \
              --conf "spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=./environment/bin/python" \
              --conf "spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1" \
              --conf "spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./environment/bin/python" \
              --conf "spark.speculation=true" \
              --archives app.zip#app,environment.tar.gz#environment \
              --driver-cores 16 \
              --executor-cores 16 \
              --driver-memory 32G \
              --executor-memory 16G \
              --num-executors 100 \
              --deploy-mode client \
              --master yarn my_file.py
```

In cluster mode the python environment is from ./environment/bin/python whereas in client mode its picking local python installation.

Comment: Because in client mode Spark can't find `./environment/bin/python` locally?